# No Ad Available when using Windows 10 Advertising SDK for XAML with UWP

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to add adverts to my UWP app so I thought I'd follow up the walkthrough provided by Microsoft i.e. [Windows 10 Advertising SDK Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt125365(v=msads.100).aspx), but I can't get it to work.

I've followed the steps i.e.

1. Added a reference to `Microsoft Advertising SDK for XAML` (V10.0.0.0)
2. Made sure the `Platform` is `x86`
3. Added the namespace to my page: `xmlns:UI="using:Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"`
4. Added the following XAML to my `<Grid>`:

   ```
   <UI:AdControl ApplicationId="d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab" 
                 AdUnitId="10043107"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Height="250" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="250"
                 ErrorOccurred="AdControl_ErrorOccurred" />
   ```

But it doesn't do anything. No ad displayed, no rectangle, nothing!!

As you can see from the above XAML, I've added the ErrorOccured event to see if I could spot anything else, and it does get triggered and I get the following error:

- ErrorCode: NoAdAvailable
- ErrorMessage: No Ad Available

Any ideas how to resolve this? It seems ridiculous that something that's suppose to be that simple is turning into something complicated in order to get it to work!

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I've just noticed in my Reference dialog box that I have the following entries:

1. Microsoft Advertising SDK for XAML

   - Version: 10.0
   - Targets: UAP 10.0.10240.0
   - SDK Dependencies: Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=14.0
2. Microsoft Advertising Universal SDK

   - Version: 1.0
   - Targets: UAP 10.0.0.0
   - SDK Dependencies: Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml, Version=10.0

Which one should I use? I will try both an update this post.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UWP app, please install Microsoft Universal Ad Client SDK(https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/401703a0-263e-4949-8f0f-738305d6ef4b) and use AdMediatorControl.

References:

- [Install the Universal Ad Client SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/install-the-microsoft-universal-ad-client-sdk)
- [Add and use the ad mediator control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/add-and-use-the-ad-mediator-control)

> In a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) project, use the AdMediatorControl under the AdMediator Universal section.
>
> After you’ve added all the controls you’d like, you’re ready to configure the ad networks through Connected Services.

Check my sample: https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/AdClientUWPApp

Comment: I had already done everything you suggested and thanks for taking the time to make a sample. I did end up figuring out the various issues and while it's working it's far from perfect but at least it's a start.

Comment: I've accepted your answer but one critical point I feel that missing is how important the advert size is. Using the wrong size will result in nothing to display. Even with the right size, it can still be very inconsistent and hopefully this will be fixed over time!

Comment: hi there, I have checked the link for Microsoft Universal Ad Client SDK, but "it is not published yet" . . . Help

Comment: Version 2.0.7 does not show any Microsoft ads, shows only AdDuplex ads. It's been over a month now but sadly no action yet. Fill rate is zero and so is the income from Ads :(

Comment: @NP3 This is a serious issue if you're doing right, have you report it in this forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=aiasdk There are PG team in there

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT Thanks for the Forum Link. I will definitely post the issue there. I have already posted my review on the AdMediator link you have posted above, but no reply.  There is another post saying the same thing about V 2.0.7 that is unanswered. Just today I saw a message in the Dev Center that there has been a problem since May 18 and MS is working on it.

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2017. All apps need to be using the Microsoft Store Services SDK.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/update-your-app-to-the-latest-advertising-libraries

I have updated my ads and I have found relatively low fill rates, white ad spaces, and nothing showing at all. I've contacted Microsoft and they are leaning towards the "wait and see" response.

Comment: I'm getting "no ad available" errors when running MSFT sample code: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Advertising

Answer (score 0):

It says on the walkthrough that it's a preview document, probably not official sdk release. Try this one [New advertising features and walkthrough of using Microsoft ads and mediation](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/10/08/new-advertising-features-and-walkthrough-of-using-microsoft-ads-and-mediation/)

Comment: I've had a look at the link, but the link provided in 'Core steps to adding banner ads' (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt313186(v=msads.30).aspx), it's the same article I've been following regarding what needs to be done, unless I'm missing something. Also since my last update, I my views won't display, so I can't access the toolbox to try out the other suggested method i.e. AdMediator Universal. That's for both VS & Blend! Complete pain!

Answer (score 0):

For  Microsoft Advertising , you must use  [Microsoft support sizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-ad-sizes-for-banner-ads) , so you can modify width and height in your XAML and you can refer to the following screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For googlers, [Windows Store Services SDK](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/229b7858-2c6a-4073-886e-cbb79e851211)
 is the new library that is used for showing ads in Windows store apps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a supported ad size, and make sure you're setting Width and Height correctly.  It's not obvious that Microsoft lists dimensions as Height x Width. For banner ads:

**(Height x Width)**

- 160×600
- 300×50
- 300×250
- 300×600
- 320×50
- 640×100
- 728×90

[Supported Ad Sizes for Banner Ads (Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-ad-sizes-for-banner-ads)

[Known Issues and Troubleshooting for Ads (Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/known-issues-for-the-advertising-libraries)